# Upgrade to iCloud Drive: "...devices below will not be able to access..."

Tags: icloud, macos

I'm running Yosemite on a mid-2012 MBP. When I try to upgrade to iCloud Drive on my iPad or my MBP it states that my MBP will not be able to access files on iCloud Drive until I upgrade it to Yosemite. I'm already running Yosemite. Is this a bug?

Comment: Is there any other MBP associated with your Apple ID?

Comment: No, the only other devices on this ID are an iMac and an iPad. I considered that maybe it was using my MBP name instead of my iMac name because my iMac is still running Mavericks. However, iCloud.com had all the correct computer names, so I know that it's not alerting me of the iMac (which is strange, because it should).

Comment: Any reason why your iMac isn't on Yosemite yet?

Comment: I ask because you could upgrade it and see what happens when the setup process asks you about iCloud Drive.

Comment: It's in another country and I don't use it a lot anymore, so upgrading it to Yosemite would be a waste of time. I intend to upgrade it later, just for consistency and keeping things up-to-date, but I can't now.

Comment: Wait, the MBP warns you about itself? "When I try to upgrade to iCloud Drive on my iPad or my MBP..."

Comment: Exactly. That's what doesn't make sense about this.